# In Springboot, how to serialize properties into objects when using @ConfigurationProperties and @PropertySource?

Tags: java, spring-boot, yaml

When using @ConfigurationProperties with @PropertySource(value = "myconfig.yml") Springboot doesn't serialize my properties into an object

If I put this same config in application.yml and remove the @PropertySource(value = "myconfig.yml"), then it works

```
---
testPrefix.simpleProperty: my.property.haha
testPrefix.complexProperties:
  -
    firstName: 'Clark'
    lastName: 'Ken'
  -
    firstName: 'Roger'
    lastName: 'Federer'
```

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "testPrefix")
@PropertySource(value = "testConfigFile.yml")
public class MyTestProperties {
  private String simpleProperty;
  private List<Person> complexProperties;

getters

setters
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class App implements CommandLineRunner {

  MyTestProperties myProperties;

  @Autowired
  public App(MyTestProperties properties) {
    this.properties = properties;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication app = new SpringApplication((App.class));
    app.run(args);
  }

  @Override
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(myProperties.getSimpleProperty()); 
    myProperties.getComplexProperties.stream.forEach(System.out::println));
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
my.property.haha
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use jackson yaml dependency.

```xml
//pom.xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-yaml</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Then create a factory class for loading yaml files as property sources.

```java
//YamlPropertySourceFactory.java

import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.YamlPropertiesFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.core.env.PropertiesPropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.env.PropertySource;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.EncodedResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.support.PropertySourceFactory;

public class YamlPropertySourceFactory implements PropertySourceFactory {

    @Override
    public PropertySource<?> createPropertySource(String s,
            EncodedResource encodedResource) throws IOException {
        YamlPropertiesFactoryBean bean = new YamlPropertiesFactoryBean();
        bean.setResources(encodedResource.getResource());
        return new PropertiesPropertySource(
                s != null ? s : encodedResource.getResource().getFilename(),
                bean.getObject());
    }

}
```

Then use `PropertySource` annotation like this.

```java
@PropertySource(factory = YamlPropertySourceFactory.class, value = "testConfigFile.yml")
public class MyTestProperties {
  private String simpleProperty;
  private List<Person> complexProperties;
```

Comment: Could you please answer here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/385588/was-my-edit-wrong-replacing-bit-ly-link-with-the-actual-link

Answer (score 2):

To my knowledge, YAML properties cannot be loaded using a `@PropertySource`. I'll look it up as I'm not sure whether the issue has been resolved in the meantime.

[edit]
Apparently, it [hasn't](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config-yaml-shortcomings) been fixed:

> YAML files cannot be loaded by using the @PropertySource annotation.
>   So, in the case that you need to load values that way, you need to use
>   a properties file.